# loading images in autocompletetextview suggestions using custom cursor adapter

Tags: android

I am working on an app which requires an autocompletetextview for suggesting contacts in dropdown view. I am using a custom cursor adapter. My layout for one drop down item has imageview on the left (for showing image of the contact if available, else a default image).
I have used Asynctask to load images from the contacts. In my bindView method, I have following snippet to load images from the Async task.

```
contactImage = new conactImage(viewHolder, cursor);
contactImage.execute(new String[] {userId});
```

and in the Asynctask's onPostExecute method, I set the image bitmap.

```
mViewHolder.cImage.setImageBitmap(imageResultBitmap);
```

mViewHolder is the viewholder passed as argument in the previous snippet.

The problem I am facing is a bad UX. Suppose I entered two characters in the autocompletetextview. The images show up in a second. When I scroll, the images don't change unless I wait another 2 3 seconds to get the correct image loaded. And when I scroll fast, the views flicker a lot because of the random image bitmap changes. 
I understand it is a view recycling thing, but this gets annoying. Please suggest any other possible way to do the same.

[image]
on scrolling

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you got the solution?